# She was eight years her elder!

Tags: meaning

Would you please tell me what the following sentence mean? Who is older than who?

Janet's sister was eight years her elder.

Comment: Janet's sister was eight years older than Janet. Maybe you'll get a more detailed answer on ell.stackexchange.com not on ELU.

Comment: I'm afraid the answer is right there in the first three words. "Janet's sister was". That alone makes the sentence impossible to be misparsed such that it's Janet who's older. It's quite straightforward, really. Your mistake is all in the title, where you replaced the unambiguous "Janet's sister" with a meaningless "she". Why you did that, escapes me, but if you undo that, you immediately get your answer back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Janet's sister is eight years older than Janet.

Comment: :) Why the down vote?